# Adding to RouteValueDictionary of the Url.Action at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

I have a string property named Country which is avaialble in view through all viewmodels.
I want to add this property to RouteValueDictionary of Url.Action so for now I have to change every 
Url.Action to

> Url.Action("action","controller", new RouteValueDictionary{new
>   {Country=Country})).

I am looking for clean solution, adding it to RouteValueDictionary at runtime
instead of changing the Url.Action everywhere

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it just as (using the anonymous object only):

```
Url.Action("action","controller",  new {Country=Country} )
```

Comment: I was hoping not to touch Url.Action at all for ex: Current Url.Action("action","controller", new RouteValueDictionany{new {somevalues=somevalue}}) and not to modify it all.